# POJO attributes is returning as a Array for JSON in JAX-RS

Tags: java, json, maven, jax-rs

I have a java web maven project with JAX-RS using resteasy version 2.2.1.GA implementation. All JAX-RS resources on the project produces y consumes application/json. My problem is that when I returning a single POJO, even an array of this, only serialize the values of the attributes.

Example:

Given the following classes:

```
public class Pojo {

    private Integer attr1;

    private String attr2;

    // GETTERs and SETTERs

}


@Path("pojos")
@Consumes("application/json")
@Produces("application/json")
public class PojoResource {

    @GET
    public Response list() {
        List<Pojo> listResult = new ArrayList<>();
        Pojo pojo = new Pojo();
        pojo.setAttr1(1);
        pojo.setAttr2("asdf");
        listResult.add(pojo);
        return Response.ok().entity(listResult).build();
    }
}
```

If I do a GET request to /pojos, the result for the example above is `[[1, "asdf"]]`, instead of `[{"attr1":1,"attr2":"asdf"}]`

I don't know if a need to write a specific Provider. My project configuration is similar to [this](http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/resteasy-hello-world-example/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized my mistake is that data recovery in layer model is as a vector of objects and return that without processing (create a POJO that represent the data).

Comment: Can you elaborate on your answer please? I am running JDK9, Wildfly 10 CR1, and JavaEE 7. I am return my List<MyEntity> from my JAXRS endpoint. But I am getting array of arrays instead of array of objects (e.g., `[ ["field_1_value", "field_2_value"], ["field_1_value", "field_2_value"] ]`). By the way, I am a java n00b. So everything I have is barebone default install config. The only Maven dep. I have is `javax:javaee-api`.  I already have `@XmlRootElement`, `@Entity`, and `@Table` annotations on my POJO entity.

Comment: Nevermind. I figured it out myself.  I wasn't supplying the `EntityManager`'s `em.createNativeQuery( "query" )` with the Class Type of my entity like this: `em.createNativeQuery( "query",  MyEntity.class )`.   Now my code works and the JSON output is as I expected.